# Добавление "Форма Qt Designer" в количестве больше одного в один класс

Tags: qt, ui

Изучаю аспекты ui. Для примера необходимо при нажатии на кнопку создать 3 новых окна. Возможно ли это без создания новых классов формы, а просто создать 3 формы и прикрепить их к одному классу, так как у меня сейчас ругается на `redefinition of 'class Ui_Dialog'.`

Comment: А смысл? Только усложните себе работу.

Comment: создать три одинаковых новых окна, три немного отличающихся новых окна, или три совсем разных новых окна?

Answer (score 1):

Еcли уж очень нужно,то можно так:

test.h:

```
namespace Ui {
class Test;
class Dialog;
}

class Test : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Test(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Test();

private:
    Ui::Test *ui;
    Ui::Dialog *uz;
};
```

test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"
#include "ui_test.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"

Test::Test(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Test), uz(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    uz->setupUi(this);
}
```